# Parallel test case execution with JUnit 5

Tags: java, junit, junit5

Is it possible to execute a test case parallel with JUnit 5?

I'm looking for something like `threadPoolSize` and `invocationCount` from [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests):

```
@Test(threadPoolSize = 3, invocationCount = 10,  timeOut = 10000)
```

Comment: This functionality is not available yet: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/964

Comment: The JUnit team is currently working on it: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/60

Answer (score 22):

You can write parallel tests with JUnit 5.3.
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution

```
@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
class MyTest {

    @Test
    void test1() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Test1 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    @Test
    void test2() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Test 2! " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}

// should run simultaneously
```

Remember to add the `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true` to your JUnit configuration

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-config-params

Add this to your JUnit configuration if you need a `fixed thread pool`:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=4
```

Comment: is there some way to enable it under specific conditions? For example, `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "tests.run-concurrently", havingValue = "true")` (doesn't work)

Comment: The @Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT) annotation in JUnit 5 is a static declaration and does not support conditional logic directly in its usage. You might make it work with a custom JUnit extension (https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-extensions) but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 2):

As of writing, Parallel test execution is an experimental feature in Junit5:

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution

Update the `junit-platform.properties` file:

> Configuration parameters to execute top-level classes in parallel but
> methods in same thread:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = same_thread
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = concurrent
```

> Configuration parameters to execute top-level classes sequentially but
> their methods in parallel:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = same_thread
```

> The default execution mode is applied to all nodes of the test tree
> with a few notable exceptions, namely test classes that use the
> Lifecycle.PER_CLASS mode or a MethodOrderer (except for Random). In
> the former case, test authors have to ensure that the test class is
> thread-safe; in the latter, concurrent execution might conflict with
> the configured execution order. Thus, in both cases, test methods in
> such test classes are only executed concurrently if the
> @Execution(CONCURRENT) annotation is present on the test class or
> method.

Answer (score 1):

For Maven:

```
// JUnit 5
@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
abstract class BaseTest {
}


// pom.xml
<properties>
    <!-- CLI parameters -->
    <ignore-failure />
    <include-tags />
    <exclude-tags />
    <parallel-enabled />
    <thread-count />
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M8</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>${ignore-failure}</testFailureIgnore>
                <groups>${include-tags}</groups>
                <excludedGroups>${exclude-tags}</excludedGroups>
                <properties>
                    <configurationParameters>
                        junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=${parallel-enabled}
                        junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
                        junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=${thread-count}
                        junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.max-pool-size=${thread-count}
                    </configurationParameters>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```