# tun unit tests in parallel and other test sequentially in the same run spring boot kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit, parallel-testing

i am having an issue to understand how can i run all the unit tests in my boot spring application(kotlin) in parallel while the springBootTests and the dataJpaTests will run one after the other(becouse they are failing due to shared context where running in parallel),
my application structure is separated to different models and each model have it's unit,springBootTests and dataJpaTets, like this:

-module 1:

- unit test 1
- unit test 2
- data jpa test 1
- data jpa test 2
- spring boot test1

-module 2:

- unit test 1
- unit test 2
- unit test 3
- data jpa test 1
- spring boot test1

i used the following properties from https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution:

junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true

junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent //tests in each class run in parallel

junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = concurrent //classes run in parallel

but it is not helping becouse there is no way to exclude the springBoot and dataJpa tests from the parallization.

also,i tried to put the @Execution(SAME_THREAD) on all the dataJpa and springBoot test but still
the classes itself runed in parallel and test was colliding

*i use --test *test commend to run all the tests together

Comment: #1 java, maven, spring boot and junit version? #2 Do you only need to exclude some test class from the parallel execution? #3 It helps you to run first the parallel test (excluding some tests) and after that just run the excluded tests? #4 Are you using shell with maven or IDE to run the tests?

Comment: i am using kotlin 1.5 and gradel(not maven) , spring boot version is 2.6.8 and junit 5. it doesn't meter for me in which order to run the tests, only that i will be able parallelize most of them. and because i know i cant parallelize spring boot and data jpa tests i decided to try to parallelize only the unit tests

Answer (score 0):

### Spring uses Junit

By default, JUnit Jupiter tests **are run sequentially** in a single thread.

Running tests in parallel — for example, to speed up execution — is available as an **experimental feature** since version 5.3

Source: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution

### Using pure Junit

```
@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
class MyTest {

    @Test
    void test1() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Test1 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    @Test
    void test2() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Test 2! " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

source:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55244698/3957754
- https://www.swtestacademy.com/junit5-parallel-test-execution/

### Using spring + maven + junit

```
<build>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <parallel>methods</parallel>
            <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</build>
```

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Spring5JUnit4ConcurrentTest.SimpleConfiguration.class)
public class Spring5JUnit4ConcurrentTest implements ApplicationContextAware, InitializingBean {

    @Configuration
    public static class SimpleConfiguration {}

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private boolean beanInitialized = false;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        this.beanInitialized = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(
      final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Test
    void test1A() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" => test1A");
    }
    
    @Test
    void test1B() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" => test1B");
    }
    @Test
    void testC() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" => test1C");
    }  

}
```

Sources:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-concurrent-tests
- https://javabydeveloper.com/junit-5-parallel-tests-execution-and-resourcelock-examples/
- [Running junit tests in parallel in a Maven build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423627/running-junit-tests-in-parallel-in-a-maven-build)
- [Running junit testcases in parallel using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54349261/)

### Simple tests are "almost parallel"

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1098480/3957754) and my tests, simple junit tests are executed  **almost parallel**

```
public class Hello1Test {
    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {
      System.out.println(new Date());
      assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

`mvn test`

[image]

NOTE: If you add some Thread related in the test, they are executed sequentially

```
  @Test
  public void myTest() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(new Date());
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      assertTrue(true);
  }
```

[image]

### Exclude some tests

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53008592/3957754) you could use **-Dtest** to pick or exclude specific tests

- mvn test -q

  - run all tests
- mvn test -q -Dtest='Hello1*'

  - run only test with name Hello1*
- mvn test -q -Dtest='!Hello1*, !Hello2*'

  - run all tests except Hello1* and Hello2*

[image]

### Tips

- Use the shell, it never lies
- According to your ide (eclipse or intellij), you should be able to configure jvm args like : `mvn test -q -Dtest`
- Add date and test name to the log to verify if they are parallel or sequential
- Create a minimal reproducible project to help you. Example: https://github.com/jrichardsz/spring-boot-templates/tree/master/011-filter-tests

Comment: it seems that your assumption is wrong.

Comment: Tests are NOT run in parallel by default. You have to explicitly enable parallel execution.

Your test does not prove they are parallel: such simple tests will take only a tiny fraction of a second and it is therefore quite expected that they all run in the same second even if they are run sequentially.

Comment: You are right. I already updated it